# Delete key from registery

Tags: vb.net, registry

Hey all i am trying to delete a key from the registery but i cant seem to get it correct.

My code looks like this:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim tmpKey As String = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"
    Dim foundKey As RegistryKey = My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(tmpKey, True)

    If Not (foundKey Is Nothing) Then
        foundKey.DeleteSubKey("Billy")
    Else
        MsgBox("not found")
    End If
End Sub
```

The tree looks like this:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMxxL.png)

It keeps saying it can not find that key... Any help would be great.

David

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you are trying to delete a value("Billy") in the subkey("Run").

If so, you would need to use the **DeleteValue**() method instead of **DeleteSubKey**().

```
If Not (foundKey Is Nothing) Then
    foundKey.DeleteValue("Billy")
Else
    MsgBox("not found")
End If
```

Comment: Correct, "Billy" seems to be a value in subkey Run. So, you can't use delete DeleteSubKey for a value. +1 @Unomono